# Can I create a TensorBoard visualization from pre-trained unsummarized checkpoint files?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have implemented the sequence to sequence model in Tensorflow for about 100,000 steps without specifying the summarizing operations required for TensorBoard.

I have the checkpoint log files for every 1000 steps. Is there any way to visualize the data without having to retrain the entire model i.e. extract the summaries from the checkpoint files to feed to TensorBoard?

I tried running TensorBoard directly on the checkpoint files, which obviously said no scalar summaries found. I also tried inserting the summary operations in code but it requires me to completely retrain the model for the summaries to get created.